# what happen when we pass arguments inside the function itself?

Tags: javascript

Kindly Accept my apologies for being a beginner in JS.
I stopped studying JS on a point of what is the correct answer of what happen inside a function when passing arguments, let us describe by code snippet.

```
function myFun(x){
   console.log(arguments);
   console.log(x);
}
myFun(1);
```

according to the above example, 
is the correct action happened is :

**Example 1**

```
when passing calling myFun(1) this will do : 
    function myFunction(x){
    var x = 1
    }
```

**OR**
**Example 2**

```
 function myFunction(x,y,z){
    x=arguments[0];
    y=arguments[1];
    z=arguments[2];
    }
```

according to the [main documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6), i didn't find the desired approach, what i found in arguments object creation process  is that:

> Repeat while indx >= 0,
>   Let val be the element of args at 0-origined list position indx.

which I couldn't specify this related to the process of assigning the values or not.

So according to above at all ,

**which solution is the correct?**
**how arguments assigned to parameters? if we passed value 1 as an argument , in the function scope, 1 will be assigned to x or 1 will be assigned to arguments Object?**

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: There is a LOT of confusion in the comment thread you linked, and it sounds like you are confused by it all. There is no "assignment", just argument passing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : i will edit this point

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar : check it with bold line if it isn't clearly shown

Comment: Are you trying to ask "Are the variables declared as argument names globally or locally scoped?"?

Comment: @Quentin : how arguments assigned to parameters? if we passed value 1 as an argument , in the function scope, 1 will be assigned to x or 1 will be assigned to arguments Object?

Comment: @youhana — Have you considered testing it? If you run the code in the first snippet, it clearly shows up in **both**.

Comment: @Quentin : still i don't know which snippet is the correct , are passed arguments set from the arguments object as the second example or the passed arguments will be assigned to the named parameter like x in the first example?

Comment: @youhana see my ans and edit

Comment: @youhana — They appear in both. That's all that matters. Everything else is an implementation detail of the underlying JavaScript engine. It's entirely irrelevent unless you want to edit the source code of that JavaScript engine. … and in that case it depends on which JS engine you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function like this:

```
function oneParam(x)
{
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Calling it like so: `oneParam(1);` will put the first parameter passed in, into the arguments array. If you run the above code, you will get the same value printed twice, because they are the same.

`1`

`1`

---

Now let's take a function with multiple params:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z)
{
    console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);

    x=arguments[0];
    y=arguments[1];
    z=arguments[2];

    console.log(x, y, z);
}
```

You will notice, that calling this function like this `myFunction("a","b","c");` will produce two similar outputs.

`a b c`

`a b c`

So essentially, both scenarios are correct. Just depends on what you passed in when calling the function.

---

**Edit:** To clarify, the arguments object will have all the params you passed in. These params will, in order, be assigned to named variables that are there in the function signature.

So you can even have `oneParam(1, 2, 3);` and the arguments object will have all three params, but only the first param `1` will be assigned to the function variable x.

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/g74gqyn2/1/)

Comment: so you encourage the second example mentioned in the post?

Comment: You don't have to manually assign the values from the arguments object to your vars. It is done automatically. I just did it to show you what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: So in essence, don't bother with the second one, just go with the first.

Comment: @youhana pls accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: actually, your answer didn't solve the problem. thanks for your time but still I am waiting for the best-referenced answer.

Comment: @youhana what point specifically are you looking for a reference to?

Answer (score 0):

If you name arguments in your function like this:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z)
{
    console.log(x, y, z);
}
```

then it's better to access them by their names directly.
You can use `argumens` if you don't know the number of the arguments while defining the function, like `Math.max()`, for example.

ES6 makes use of arguments slightly easier than it was before, but it's quite similar. Just remember that `arguments` **is not an array**, therefore it has to be converted to an array if you want to have access to all array's methods.

```
function myFunc_ES6() {
    var args = [...arguments];
    // or
    //var args = Object.values(arguments)

    args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

function myFunc_ES5() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

    args.forEach(function(arg) {
        console.log(arg);
    });
}

myFunc_ES6(1,2,3,4);
myFunc_ES5(6,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Arguments Object
> JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object.
>
> The argument object contains an array of the arguments used when the function
> was called (invoked).

as stated in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

`arguments` can be used when you don't want to explicitly specify the parameters of a function. This can be useful in many situations.
Eg.

> different behavior on different arguments count

```
function foo() {
   if(arguments.length == 2){
     // do something
   }else{
     //do something else
   }
}
```

> extending some method

```
var oldMethod = Object.prototype.method;
Object.prototype.method = function() {
 // some extended functionality
 // then call the original
 oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

> working with unknown number of arguments

```
function average(){
  var i, s=0;

  if(!arguments.length){
     throw('Division by zero.');
  }
 
  for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    s+=arguments[i];
  }
  return s/arguments.length;
}
```

Regarding the way the values get assigned,
if we have a function:

```
function foo(x){}
```

no matter what you pass in as parameters thiswill be true:

```
x === arguemnts[0]
```

It is almost like x is staticaLly referenced in the arguments, because operating on arguments alters the refs too:

```
arguments[0]++;
x === arguments[0] // true
```

however deleting the arguments[0] will not modify the explicit parameter value

```
delete arguments[0]
x !== undefined
```